# How to do UAT on our containerized Spring-batch application

Tags: docker, spring-batch, acceptance-testing

We have a Spring-batch (3.0.8) application using db2 for data persistence.

We have built Docker image of the application and are trying to figure out how to test it using Jenkins pipeline.  We launch the application using CommandLineJobRunner in a format similar to this:

```
bluecost-docker]$ docker run -v /home/bluecost/config:/home/bluecost/config -v /home/bluecost/data:/home/bluecost/data -v /home/bluecost/logs:/home/bluecost/logs bluecost com.mycomp.cloud.cost.LoadBMSData CommandLineJobRunner load-bms-job-xml LoadBMSJob ../data/input/CSVMapping-Mar2018.csv
```

The results of the job are recorded in the DB2 database table.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to test this containerized application that doesn't expose a RESTful interface to the outside world.

The goals of the testing is User Acceptance.  The test scenarios are done using Cucumber (Features > Scenarios > Tests).  The testing must check the results of the job run (db table) against the expected outcomes.

Question:  Do we have to write an integration layer around the jobs so we can launch them using REST and retrieve the results using REST or is there some other way?!